# Upper bound of function including Pochhammer symbol

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, asymptotics, gamma-function

How can I find the upper bound of $$\left\vert\frac{(c+1/2+\lambda)_{n}}{\lambda^{n}}\right\vert,\quad\text{where}\quad(c+1/2+\lambda)_{n}=\frac{\Gamma(c+1/2+\lambda+n)}{\Gamma(c+1/2+\lambda)}$$ and $\lambda \to \infty$?

Comment: [Leo August Pochhammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_August_Pochhammer) :)

Comment: What kind of upper bound? The limit is 1.

Comment: And the ratio decreases to its limit 1.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left\vert\frac{(c+1/2+\lambda)_{n}}{\lambda^{n}}\right\vert
=\left\vert\frac{(c+1/2+\lambda)}{\lambda}\right
\vert\left\vert\frac{(c+1/2+\lambda -1)}{\lambda}\right\vert...
\left\vert\frac{(c+1/2+\lambda -n+1)}{\lambda}\right\vert$$

each term goes to 1 when $\lambda \to \infty$. so the limit is 1 as mentioned in the two comments above.